# How to round variable values down to next lowest number from an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm working on a macro in Excel using VBA. I have an array of numbers like:

```
180, 190, 300, 390, 400, 430, ...
```

I then have a variable with a value of, say, `307` or `389` or `425`. How can I round this number down to the next lowest number contained in the array without using a bunch of `If` statements?

For example, I would need to change:

```
307 -> 300
389 -> 300
425 -> 400
```

What would be a faster way to do this than using a long list of logic statements?

Comment: Is the array of numbers sorted?

Comment: The array is just manually defined, so it can be sorted however it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is sorted, you can just use `HLOOKUP()`. If you specify `True` for the last parameter, it will match the closest *previous* value. For example:

```
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.HLookup(307, Array(180, 190, 300, 390, 400, 430), 1, True)
```

Output:

```
300
```

You would just need to guard against numbers less than the lowest number (180, in this case). So you may want to start your array with a value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()
Dim aValues(1 To 5) As Integer
Dim i As Integer

aValues(1) = 180
aValues(2) = 190
aValues(3) = 300
aValues(4) = 390
aValues(5) = 400

Dim iFindValue As Integer
iFindValue = 310

'First make sure we have a valid value to check for.
If aValues(1) > iFindValue Then
    MsgBox ("Lowest value in the array is greater than variable.")
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through the array
For i = 1 To UBound(aValues)
    'If we are at the end of the array, we haven't found it so set the value to the highest slot in the array.
    If i = UBound(aValues) Then
        iFindValue = aValues(i)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'If it is in between the current slot value and the next one, set it to the current. Effectively rounding it down.
    If aValues(i) < iFindValue And aValues(i + 1) > iFindValue Then
        iFindValue = aValues(i)
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

You said your array could be sorted, but if for some reason it wasn't, you could do something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()
Dim aValues(1 To 5) As Integer
Dim i As Integer

aValues(1) = 180
aValues(2) = 190
aValues(3) = 300
aValues(4) = 390
aValues(5) = 400

Dim iFindValue As Integer
iFindValue = 310

Dim iTemp As Integer
Dim iDifference As Integer
iDifference = 32000

For i = 1 To UBound(aValues)

    'Find the difference
    iTemp = iFindValue - aValues(i)
    'If it is the smallest difference found so far, record it
    If iTemp > 0 And iTemp < iDifference Then
        iDifference = iTemp
    End If
Next i

'Make the adjustment
iFindValue = iFindValue - iDifference

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the array is sorted, you could use:

```
Function RoundTo(A As Variant, num As Long) As Variant
    'returns greatest number in A which is <= num
    'returns False if no such number exists
    'assumes A is a sorted array of numbers

    Dim i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(num, A, 1)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        RoundTo = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    RoundTo = A(LBound(A) + i - 1)

End Function
```

Used like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant, i As Long
    A = Array(12, 15, 19, 25, 39)
    Debug.Print RoundTo(A, 45)
    Debug.Print RoundTo(A, 18)
    Debug.Print RoundTo(A, 12)
    Debug.Print RoundTo(A, 11)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
 39 
 15 
 12 
False
```

You could of course tweak it to return something other than `False` when the number is too small to be rounded to any number in your list of numbers